# Writing a SQL request with a CTE and counting its rows

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, common-table-expression, window-functions

I have two tables: `Contacts` and `Messages`. I'd like to fetch a Chat structure that doesn't belong to any table (in other words: there's no `Chats` table I just want to build a query) This query should contain:

- A `contact` I'm referring to in that chat
- A `lastMessage` between me and that contact (If I don't have a last message w/ that contact - I should get no result from that contact specifically)
- `unreadCount` that tells how many messages inside that conversation are not read yet.

### My tables are:

1. Contacts

- `uniqueId` (Blob)
- `username` (Text)

2. Messages

- `isRead` (Bool)
- `sender` (Blob)
- `receiver` (Blob)
- `timestamp` (Integer)

The farthest I got was this:

```
WITH 
"lastMessage" AS (
    SELECT *, MAX("timestamp") 
    FROM "messages" 
    GROUP BY "sender", "receiver"
),
"unreadCount" AS (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM "messages" WHERE "isRead" = 0
    GROUP BY "sender"
)

SELECT "contacts".*, "unreadCount".*, "lastMessage".* 
FROM "contacts" 

JOIN "lastMessage" 
ON ("lastMessage"."sender" = "contacts"."uniqueId") 
OR ("lastMessage"."receiver" = "contacts"."uniqueId") 

LEFT JOIN "unreadCount" 
ON "unreadCount"."sender" = "contacts"."uniqueId" 

ORDER BY "lastMessage"."timestamp" DESC
```

PS: The sender/receiver of a message is equal to a contact uniqueId (or my own uniqueId and vice-versa)

The issue with the current result I'm having is that its fetching duplicate chats for each contact (considering each one of them has a sent and a received message) and its not working to fetch the un-reads

Edit 1: Here's what I'm looking for...

I have on my DB:

```
Contacts table:

- username: John Doe, 
  uniqueId: (Blob...)

- username: Alice Shrek, 
  uniqueId: (Blob...)

Messages table:

- sender: (Blob from my uniqueId), 
  receiver: (Blob from John Doe), 
  isRead: true, 
  timestamp: ...1

- sender: (Blob from John Doe), 
  receiver: (Blob from my uniqueId), 
  isRead: false, 
  timestamp: ...2

- sender: (Blob from my uniqueId), 
  receiver: (Blob from Alice Shrek), 
  isRead: true, 
  timestamp: ...3

- sender: (Blob from Alice Shrek), 
  receiver: (Blob from my uniqueId), 
  isRead: false, 
  timestamp: ...4
```

(In other words, this hypothetical scenario I have two contacts and two messages w/ each of those contacts. One message I sent which is the read one and one I received which is the unread one)

I want my query to fetch these:

```
- username: John Doe, 
  uniqueId: (Blob from John doe), 
  sender: (Blob from John doe)
  receiver: (Blob from my uniqueId)
  timestamp: ...2
  unreadCount: 1

- username: Alice Shrek, 
  uniqueId: (Blob from Alice Shrek), 
  sender: (Blob from Alice Shrek)
  receiver: (Blob from my uniqueId)
  timestamp: ...4
  unreadCount: 1
```

Comment: *it fetches way more information that I need* what information do you need? Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Comment: What is `direct_messages`? Also, do you want results for a specific user only (the one you refer to as "me") or for all users?

Comment: `direct_messages` is the equivalent of `messages`, i just fixed the query example to not show `direct_messages` so it is not confusing. I want the results for all contacts I have IF they have a lastMessage. If they don't, it means I have never chat-ed w/ them. @forpas

Comment: "for all contacts **I** have...". This is my question: you want results for all contacts **a specific user** has and not for all contacts **all users** have. Right?

Comment: The only user there is is me, everyone is my contact so yes: "all contacts a specific user has"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window function `ROW_NUMBER()` to identify the last message and `TOTAL()` to get the total number of unread messages of each contact:

```
WITH
  person(uniqueId) AS (VALUES (?)),
  aggregates AS (
    SELECT *, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MIN(m.sender, m.receiver), MAX(m.sender, m.receiver) ORDER BY timestamp DESC) rn,
           TOTAL(NOT m.isRead) OVER (PARTITION BY MIN(m.sender, m.receiver), MAX(m.sender, m.receiver)) unreadCount
    FROM Messages m INNER JOIN person p 
    ON p.uniqueId IN (m.sender, m.receiver)
  )
SELECT c.username, c.uniqueId,
       a.sender, a.receiver, a.timestamp, a.unreadCount 
FROM aggregates a CROSS JOIN person p 
INNER JOIN Contacts c 
ON c.uniqueId = CASE WHEN a.sender = p.uniqueId THEN a.receiver ELSE a.sender END
WHERE a.rn = 1;
```

Replace `?` in the cte `person` with your `uniqueId`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=70c12d7b2193c589d75b1d1f297b0f3c).

Answer (score 1):

I think this has all you want in it ... EDIT: First pass missed Unread count!

```
DECLARE @Me int = 104;

with cteConatacts as (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES (101, 'Bob'), (102, 'Alice')
        , (103, 'Chris'), (104, 'Me')) as Contacts(ContactID, ContactName)
), cteMessages as (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1, 101, 103, 1001, 'Hi Chris')
        , (1, 101, 104, 1002, 'Hi friend')
        , (1, 104, 101, 1003, 'Hi Bob')
        , (0, 104, 102, 1004, 'Hi Alice')
    ) as Mess(IsRead, SenderID, RecvID, Timestmp, MsgBody)
), cteThreadsWithMe as (
    SELECT 'Sent' as Direction, @Me as MyID, M.RecvID as TheirID,  M.* 
    FROM cteMessages as M 
    WHERE M.SenderID = @Me 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Recv' as Direction, @Me as MyID, M.SenderID as TheirID,  M.* 
    FROM cteMessages as M 
    WHERE M.RecvID = @Me 
), cteGrouped as (
    SELECT * 
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MyID, TheirID ORDER BY Timestmp DESC) as Newness
    FROM cteThreadsWithMe
), cteReadCounts as (
    SELECT G.MyID, G.TheirID, Count(*) as MessageCount, SUM( IsRead) as ReadCount
    FROM cteGrouped as G
    GROUP BY G.MyID, G.TheirID 
)
SELECT CM.ContactName as MyName, CT.ContactName as TheirName,G.* , C.MessageCount - C.ReadCount as UnreadCount
FROM cteGrouped as G 
    INNER JOIN cteConatacts as CM on CM.ContactID = G.MyID 
    INNER JOIN cteConatacts as CT on CT.ContactID = G.TheirID 
    INNER JOIN cteReadCounts as C on C.MyID = G.MyID AND C.TheirID = G.TheirID 
WHERE Newness = 1
```

Output:

| MyName | TheirName | Direction | MyID | TheirID | IsRead | SenderID | RecvID | Timestmp | MsgBody | Newness | UnreadCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Me | Bob | Sent | 104 | 101 | 1 | 104 | 101 | 1003 | Hi Bob | 1 | 0 |
| Me | Alice | Sent | 104 | 102 | 0 | 104 | 102 | 1004 | Hi Alice | 1 | 1 |

Answer (score -2):

Below Query will be helpful to you.

```
Declare @Myid int 
set @Myid = 3

select Sender.username [Sender] , receiver.username [Receiver],
Last_msg.isRead,
Last_msg.timestamp,
Last_msg.UnReadCount
From contact
cross apply  (select  top(1) * , sum(case when Messages.isRead = true then 1 else 0 end) over(order by @Myid) UnReadCount
                                            from Messages 
                                                where (contact.uniqueId = Messages.receiver and @Myid = Messages.sender) or 
                                                (contact.uniqueId = Messages.sender and @Myid = Messages.receiver)
                                                order by timestamp desc) Last_msg
join contact Sender on
Sender.uniqueId = Last_msg.sender
join contact receiver on
receiver.uniqueId = Last_msg.receiver
```

Here You just need to make sure the data type of isRead. I have tested with 0/1 but in your case true and false I have changed it you just need to make sure.  `Messages.isRead = true`
If you will have any issues just comment to me Thanks.

[image]

Comment: The question is tagged SQLite and not SQL Server.